# Disable dragging for "origin" marker in Google Maps v3 Directions API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to display a map using v3 of Google Maps Directions API. I can't figure out how to enable dragging on the marker for the "destination" and disable the dragging for the "origin" marker.

I understand this can be set here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions

however, how to access the correct marker to disable dragging? by zIndex? I've also tried
    response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ].start_location 
with no effect. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

**Figured It Out, Ya'll:**

Link: [Customer Marker Example, with some minor changes show below:](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_icons_draggable.html)

Edit (change in **bold**):

// for disabled dragging (origen:) (line 78)
startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green", **false**);

// for enabled dragging: (destination) (line 108)
endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red", **true**);

// update createMarker function (line 175)
createMarker(latlng, lable, html, color, **drag**)

// update google.maps.Marker (line 178)
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        draggable: **drag**,
        map: map,
        shadow: iconShadow,
        icon: getMarkerImage(color),
        shape: iconShape,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

**Note:  you will also need the markers, found [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/marker_green.png) and [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/marker_red.png) - and place in a folder in the same dir as code called "mapIcons/" **